# Angular 2 excel export not working

Tags: excel, spring-mvc, angular

I have created sample project to export data in excel format using JExcelApi lib. Project has Angular 2 frontend and spring mvc(rest api) backend. If I deploy backend to tomcat and make request via browser then it is exporting excel file correctly but when i make same http call using angular 2(typescript) then it is writing url of my api in the excel file and it shows as corrupted excel file.

Project is located at following github location

[NG2 Excel Export demo](https://github.com/pritspatel/NG2ExcelExportImportDemo.git)

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my service or app.component.ts file?

Here is the codebase in app.component.ts, which I think is causing the issue

```
downloadExcel(){
console.log("Downloading excel from server....")
this.fileService.downloadFile()
    .subscribe(data => window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(data)),
        error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
        () => console.log('Completed file download.'));
```

}

and here is the service class which returns the data

```
 downloadFile(){
    let url = "http://localhost:9999/api/download";
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('responseType', 'arraybuffer');
    return this._http.get( url)
        .map(res => new Blob([res],{ type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }))
        .catch((error : any ) => Observable.throw(error));
}
```

Comment: No one is going to look through your entire repository for a bug. You need to be specific and pinpoint where exactly the issue lies, **then** we can help

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated original comment with code snippets which I think is the issue. I also tried responsType Blob but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue with FileSaver.js, just in case if someone had this problem. Look at the above github project

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `window.location.assign(link);` instead.